# I didn't know that would happen when 'lazy loading' JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I created the example below where the page loads the temp.js dynamically at the bottom of the HTML page. The temp.js has a little sleep function which binds up browser for 3 seconds before logging 'Script Loaded'. At the very bottom of the HTML page it logs a 'Page Loaded'

Now, knowing what I know about browsers, downloading resources and the single threaded nature of JS I thought this would happen.

1. HTML is displayed
2. console.log 'Page Loaded'
3. About a three seconds wait whilst temp.js does it stuff
4. console.log telling me 'Script Loaded'

but what in fact happens is this

1. console.log 'Page Loaded' (almost instantly)
2. Blank page for about three seconds
3. HTML is displayed and console.log telling me 'Script Loaded'

Is this the behaviour you would have expected?

---

```
function sleep (ms) {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime ();
  while ((now + ms) > ((new Date()).getTime ())) {
  }
}
sleep (3000);
console.log ('Script Loaded');
```

---

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>querySelectorAll</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="nick">
      <img src="image.png" alt="" width="10" height="10" />
      <img src="image.png" alt="" width="10" height="10" />
      <img src="image.png" alt="" width="10" height="10" />
    </div>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = 'temp.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
      })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log('Page Loaded');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try it in different browsers, I believe the behaviour will be different. The best way is of course to add either "defer" or "async" to the script tag.

Comment: What happens when you have that code in the `window.onload` event?

Comment: I don't know what to expect from browser to browser so I use the YUI 2 event utility's [onDomReady](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#ondomready) event.

Comment: Is there a question in your question? It sounds like you're asking for opinions.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using your sleep function instead of  `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: @Rich - I have tried it in various browsers and they all seem to do a similar thing (thereabouts), which is to wait for the sleep function. I thought the sleep process would happen in the background.

Comment: @everyone above - I wasn't particularly clear in my post. I'm not trying to fix anything. I just wanted to see what other people thought. For some reason I just thought the sleep function process would happen in the background whilst the page loaded. I didn't realise it would hold up the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens

- Some HTML is parsed
- `<script>` block 1 is parsed and it adds a new script tag to the `<head>`
- `<script>` block 2 is parsed and it logs page is loaded
- `<script>` block in head is parsed and it runs your blocking sleep function
- 3 seconds pass
- Script loaded is logged
- `<head>` block has finished parsing and it renders the `<body>`
- Page is displayed.

Change

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);`

To

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(e);`

And the HTML page will load first.

The problem is *that* **all scripts in the `<head>` have to be loaded and run before the HTML body is rendered**

Comment: Thanks Raynos. That was a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the support or behaviour of `async` is across browsers, but I suspect the main problem is with your `sleep` function.

Usually a sleep function will do exactly what it says - pause the currently executing thread and wake it up again in `x` seconds. Your sleep function is doing anything but - it is executing the while loop conditional `(now + ms) > ((new Date()).getTime ())` as many times as the browser is capable of. This will certainly lock up any other Javascript execution, and depending on the browser would presumably affect page rendering as well.

You want to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to emulate sleep in Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
console.log ('Script Loaded');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks roryf. The function was supposed to do that as I wanted to see what would happen if the browser was locked into a JS process which was loaded dynamically. I wasn't very clear but I wanted to know why the page still didn't load whilst this was happening but Raynos above gave me the answer which is to append the script to the body and not the head.